# Does anyone have Adding Custom Headers to Java HttpServletRequest actually working in a Filter?

Tags: java, servlet-filters, tomcat9

I've tried using the following code:

[Adding custom headers to Java HttpServletRequest](https://wilddiary.com/adding-custom-headers-java-httpservletrequest/)

In a Filter under Tomcat 9 but my values are not being put in the request headers.

I've added the Filter mapping to the root web.xml.

I know it's using the Filter because I also print values to stdout while I'm in there.

Checking the headers in the browser, I don't see the custom values.

Comment: You can't see it in the browser because the header is modified only on the server side. Why do you want to add a header to the request in the first place?

Comment: I have something that I need to pick in as a CGI Environment Variable and was told that if I modified and put it in the header, I should be able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Had to add the following to the MutableHttpServletRequest.java:

import java.util.Optional;

```
@Override
public Enumeration<String> getHeaders(String name) {
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    Optional.ofNullable(customHeaders.get(name)).ifPresent(h -> set.add(h));
    Enumeration<String> e = ((HttpServletRequest) getRequest()).getHeaders(name);
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
        // add the names of the request headers into the list
        String n = e.nextElement();
        set.add(n);
    }
    Optional.ofNullable(customHeaders.get(name)).ifPresent(h -> set.add(h));
    return Collections.enumeration(set);
}
```